# How to work with DCOM using VB6 app? I get 462 error

Tags: windows-7, vb6, windows-server-2008, com+, dcom

We have a VB6 application that uses some DLLs on local machine. Now we want to distibute the DLLs on a remote COM+ Server.

I have registred a COM application on the server and exported it as a proxy .msi installer, installed it to my local machine.

when starting the application it shows an error saying "Runtime error '462' The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable".

When I tried debuging I have found that it fails calling one of my distributed DLLs.

Question : What I am doing wrong ? and what can I do to solve it?

```
Dim oRefE As UtilitairesClientMal.Erreurs
Dim oRefTR As UtilitairesClientMal.TablesReference
```

> Set oRefE = New UtilitairesClientMal.Erreurs 'it fails here and jumps to next hilighted line

```
g_sNomMachine = oRefE.NomMachineConnecte
g_sNomUtilisateur = oRefE.NomUtilisateurConnecte
Set oRefE = Nothing
```

........

Dim MonErreur As ALWErreur.Erreur

> ```
> Set MonErreur = New ALWErreur.Erreur
> ```

- The local machine is W7 ( 32 bits )
- The server is Windows Server 2008 ( 32 bits )

Please be kind :) if anyone needs clarification that may help just comment
( I am not very experienced with VB6 nor with COM+ so excuse my ignorance :( )

Comment: Not sure because I haven't done this myself, but I believe you need to use late binding, i.e. CreateObject. Also, does the server have more than 1 network card?

Comment: @jac I have check, the server have two network cards, I check in the registry "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\DCOM" the key DCOM Protocols have as value "ncacn_ip_tcp"

Can I use IP address instead of server name ?

Comment: I don't know because that is just possibly the problem, but here are a couple of links to kb trouble shooting articles. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183930/EN-US, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269330/en-us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exacte problem was related to the fact that my server have two Network Adapters.

I fixed it by using the IP Address instead of server name :

> On my clinet machine > dcomcnfg > MYAPP Properties > Activation > Remote Server Name

Then I got a securtiy error saying "Permission denied (70)", I fixed it by changing security limits :

> On the Server > dcomcnfg > Computers > Properties > COM Sercurity > checked : Remote execution for "EVERYONE"

I hope it helps someone, one day. If anyone needs explanation I'd be happy.

Thanks to [jac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17776/jac) he gave me an idea about the problem.